# How to find and display a graph of mean square error as a function of quality factor using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Our teacher wants us to print at Matlab a graph that plots, in the *x axis*, the **quality factor**, and on the *y axis* the **mean square error**. The image is the known "lenna.jpg".

I've searched and found how to find the mse, but I didn't find anything that helps me on how we find the quality factor.

So, can you please tell me in Matlab code, how to find these 2 things and how to display them in a graph?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your teacher never told you what quality factor is? I am betting he/she did. Does this have anything to do with degrees of compression of .jpg files? And mean square error is `sum((image1(:)-image2(:)).^2)/numel(image1);` . And I believe the image is `lena.jpg` not `lenna.jpg` - a very famous picture in image processing.

Comment: `imwrite(f,’picture.jpg’,’quality’,q)` allows you to write a picture with variable quality factor (compression). Combine this with the above for different values of `q`, and you're there. If you can't work it out, you probably shouldn't be in that class.

Comment: Also, [this](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/FFT_tests/lena_lowpass/lena.jpg) may be what your teacher had in mind when she mentioned "lena". It's a commonly used source image in image processing.

Comment: You might find [this link](http://uugan.posterous.com/hey-programmers-who-is-lena-p) instructive. Lena was a Playboy centerfold. It is pretty astonishing that lecturers still use this in the current age. You ought to complain.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have matlab available right now, but I think the following should work:

```
original=imread('lena.jpg');
mse=zeros(1,100);
for q = 1:100
    tempFile = sprintf('lena%03d.jpg', q);
    imwrite(original, tempfile, 'quality', q);
    thisOne = imread(tempfile);
    mse(q) = sum((original - thisOne).^2)/numel(thisOne);
end

figure
plot(1:100, mse)
xlabel 'quality factor'
ylabel 'MSE'
title 'Degradation of Lena.jpg with quality factor'
```